# help geocoding a vb.net dataset

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, maps, geocoding

i am looking to map a dataset of addresses on a map.

basically, i want the users to type a street name in my town and be able to see the houses that have signed up already on that street. so a pinpoint should show up on the houses that came up on the dataset.

at first i was thinking of just geocoding all the address and uploading the excel sheet into a database however, this wont work because new signups would then lack longitudes and latitudes

so what i am aiming to do is geocode the addresses on server side and then mapping the geocoded results

Comment: yeah im basically looking to see if theres a control that could automatically take my datalist of addresses and map them

Comment: do i need to get the long and lat before mapping my addresses on a map or can i just map the address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Artem Google Maps control, available on Codeplex.com will let you geocode using the Google Map API from an address. If you have a very large number of records you want to geocode, I recommend MS Mappoint, which has a COM API that can easily be called from .NET.